# How to fix this Hexadecimal to Binary Converter?

Tags: java

I have the following code. The issue is that the code is not working when I enter 0-9 characters. Where is the problem?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Enter a hex digit
    System.out.print("Enter a hex digit: ");
    String hexString = input.nextLine();

    // Enter one character
    if (hexString.length() != 1) {
        System.out.println("You must enter exactly one character");
    }

    // Display binary number for the hex digit
    char hexchar = hexString.charAt(0);

    if ((hexchar >= 'A' && hexchar <= 'F') || (hexchar >= 0 && hexchar <= 9))
    {
        System.out.print("The binary value is ");
        switch(hexchar)
        {
            case 0: System.out.println(0000); break; 
            case 1: System.out.println(0001); break; 
            case 2: System.out.println(0010); break; 
            case 3: System.out.println(0011); break; 
            case 4: System.out.println(0100); break; 
            case 5: System.out.println(0101); break; 
            case 6: System.out.println(0110); break; 
            case 7: System.out.println(0111); break; 
            case 8: System.out.println(1000); break; 
            case 9: System.out.println(1001); break; 
            case 'A': System.out.println(1010); break; 
            case 'B': System.out.println(1011); break; 
            case 'C': System.out.println(1100); break; 
            case 'D': System.out.println(1101); break; 
            case 'E': System.out.println(1110); break; 
            case 'F': System.out.println(1111); break; 
        }
    }
    else
        System.out.println(hexchar + " is and invalid input");

    }
}
```

I expect the code only accept one digit, and then convert it to the binary number. If not, show an error, or add a Handling Exception

EDIT: **(WORKING)**

```
    if ((hexchar >= 'A' && hexchar <= 'F') || (hexchar >= '0' && hexchar <= '9'))
    {
        System.out.print("The binary value is ");
        switch(hexchar)
        {
            case '0': System.out.println("0000"); break; 
            case '1': System.out.println("0001"); break; 
            case '2': System.out.println("0010"); break; 
            case '3': System.out.println("0011"); break; 
            case '4': System.out.println("0100"); break; 
            case '5': System.out.println("0101"); break; 
            case '6': System.out.println("0110"); break; 
            case '7': System.out.println("0111"); break; 
            case '8': System.out.println("1000"); break; 
            case '9': System.out.println("1001"); break; 
            case 'A': System.out.println("1010"); break; 
            case 'B': System.out.println("1011"); break; 
            case 'C': System.out.println("1100"); break; 
            case 'D': System.out.println("1101"); break; 
            case 'E': System.out.println("1110"); break; 
            case 'F': System.out.println("1111"); break; 
        }
```

Now I am editing the code for errors and to make it a little better. Thank you very much to everyone who helped.

Comment: so please tell us what is happening.

Comment: I did before what @wilmol said, but it is not working yet. It says, for example, when I enter number "4", for is an invalid input

Comment: because `4` is **not** `'4'`

Comment: I understood that, but it appears now for example as result 64 when I entered 4, but it suppose to be 0100

Comment: `System.out.println("0100");`

Comment: Thank you @ScaryWombat now it's working. I thought it suppose to work before, because it was working with A-F

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `hexchar` is a char.

You need to check '0', '1', '2' etc. not 0, 1, 2.

---

Btw `switch case` statement has a `default` keyword, use that instead of the `if else`.

Can then avoid the 'valid' character checking as all other input will go to the default case.

---

Also binary numbers should lead with `0b` (if int).

If you want to print the binary number put quotes around it e.g. "0011", so it forces the String you want.

Comment: It is not working when I change that. I thought that

Comment: so please tell us what is happening.

Comment: Works for me, did you also change to use ```(hexchar >= '0' && hexchar <= '9')``` ?

Comment: For example, if you put number four it appears "64", but it suppose to be "0100"

Comment: @GabrielGonzales then print strings i.e. put quotes around "0100".

Answer (score 1):

Gabriel.
Here you are getting the first character of a String.
for example "hola" -> 'h'
char hexchar = hexString.charAt(0);

You should compare 
case '0': System.out.println(0000); break;
case '1': etc.

Also need change this part
(hexchar >= 0 && hexchar <= 9)
to 
(hexchar >= '0' && hexchar <= '9')